# performance-wise, is multi importing better or not?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know I'm being a bit too picky but I really want to know which approach is better performance-wise in ES6:

```
import A from 'blabla/A';
import B from 'blabla/B';
import C from 'blabla/C';
```

or

```
import {A, B, C} from 'blabla';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Webpack or another [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) bundler, both are roughly equivalent.

Assuming there is some submodule D in `blabla` that you don't want or need, your first example explicitly tells Webpack that you only need A, B, and C. In the second example, Webpack pulls in them all, but then should throw away D because it isn't actually used.

There may be some MINOR efficiency gains one way or another, but it generally won't be a big deal.